# Организация выбора большого количество данных пользователям

Tags: php, mysql, sql

У меня есть БД, не сказать что слишком большая, сейчас в неё 5000 записей. Пользователям сайта нужно выводить все записи на одной странице. Теперь скажем что У меня 1000 пользователей, и каждый выводит себе эти данные по 5-10 раз в день (некоторые могут и по 20). Вот скрин статистики за сутки. 
[image: статистика]
Мне кажется что самый простой `SELECT` и дальнейший цикл вывода меня вскоре сломает.
Как организовать вывод или хранение данных, чтобы нагрузка на SQL была минимальной? Или может выборка не даёт нагрузки на сервер, и всё дело в `UPDATE`, которых у меня тоже не мало?

---

SELECT:

```
 $query = mysql_query("select * from prices order by price_status, price_csmoney_lastupdate DESC, price_item_name");
 if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    do {
        //вывод строки
    } while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query));
 }
```

Comment: Гляньте в сторону memcached.

Comment: 1. Вам действительно необходимы все поля данной таблицы?  
2. Вам действительно необходимы все записи этой таблицы на каждом хите?  
3. Используйте кеширование (продумайте срок жизни кеша) и в ,идеале, как вам посоветовали используйте  memcache или аналог

Comment: Смысл в том - чтобы вместо того, чтобы каждый раз выбирать из БД и формировать HTML - складировать это дело где-то ещё с определённым ключом. Хоть в .txt или .html файле - и потом аяксом дёргать. Про memcached уже писали - более крутое решение, работа с которым не отличается от мемкеша - tarantool от mailru - для него нет лимитов памяти, при ребуте не трётся. Но я сомневаюсь, что простой запрос таблицы 5к строк "целиком" может весомо на производительность влиять: используйте анализатор по-запросно .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Соотношение количества прочитанных строк к количеству выбранных строк говорит о том, что индексы или вообще отсутствуют или установлены неправильно.
И для 1000 пользователей по 5, 10  и даже 20 выводов данных за день количество select запросов за сутки несоразмерно большое. Нужно смотреть какие скрипты какие запросы делают. Без кода php-скриптов и mysql-запросов нельзя сказать что-то более определенное.

Comment: Добавил код php к вопросу

Comment: Ну у Вас явно не один этот select выполняется почти полмиллиона раз за сутки - это где-то получается около 5 запросов каждую секунду 24 часа в сутки. Нужно провести полный анализ всех запросов в Вашем коде. Для оптимизации нагрузки на базу данных кеширование может и не помочь, так как соотношение select к update запросам слишком маленькое, данные обновляются слишком часто.

Comment: Рекомендую залогировать каждый выполняемый запрос с координатами в коде, например в файл, хотя бы на протяжении часа. Понятно, что данных для анализа будет очень много, но Вы точно будете видеть откуда и какие запросы выполняются. А этого куска кода недостаточно. Нужно анализировать весь код, ну и проставить правильные индексы в базе данных. Индексы помогут в какой-то степени снять нагрузку с базы.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо! Буду все файлы пересмастривать.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите memcached, redis. Во многих фреймворка есть поддержка из коробки кеширование результатов запросов.

Но лучше еще и  залогировать запросы и посмотреть статистику.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441972/how-to-see-log-files-in-mysql
https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/22772/
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-logs.html